# Qt didn't continue run instructions after specific code

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to make `QInputDialog` put values into an array using a for loop but after reaching the max value it didn't continue to run code after the loop until I exit my program

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    nb = ui->lineEdit->text().toInt();

    for(i=1;i<=nb;i++)
        {
           QInputDialog *ValDialog = new QInputDialog();
           b[i] =ValDialog->getInt(this,"Best Fit","Block No : " + i,1,0,100000,1);

        }
    std::cout << "aAA\n" + b[0];

    //UNRUNABBLE instructions
}
```

Code after the for loop didn't run at all until I stopped the run.

Comment: The `getXxxx` methods are pseudo-blocking and should be deprecated. Use `show()` instead, and connect to the relevant signals of the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Qt's documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getInt `QInputDialog::getInt(...)` will create a modal window. A modal window is basically blocking the main window (your `MainWindow` class) until a user closes it.

This is intentional, so that you do not continue in the code, until a result is ready. If you wish to execute something after the dialog is shown, but not yet closed, you should probably use a different approach (maybe derive your own `QDialog`).